# ARCore_Flutter_plugin, your device isn't compatible with this version (Google Play Services for AR)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, arcore

I'm working on a flutter project and I want to use **arcore_flutter_plugin**, the AR part is one of the essential requirements of my app, I'm new to this, so I tried to run the basic example attached with the plugin documentation, I followed each step and once I run the code, the application requires me to download **Google Play Services for AR**, but Google Play Store tells me that the device incompatible with the version required

I've noticed that my device **Galaxy J6+** is not even supported by **Google ARCore**, it is not mentioned in the list. So does that mean that I need another device (supported)? is there any way to enable AR for my device so I can use the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen [here](https://developers.google.com/ar/devices#google_play), AR Core isn't supported on your device and as such, you might want to try developing with a supported device.

Comment: really feel sad to know that, because this is the only android device I have and I haven't much time before the deadline, actually I found this article (https://arpost.co/2020/08/18/how-to-enable-arcore-on-any-android-device/) which claims that we can enable AR for any device, in the worst case I will look for another device, thank you for your answer